# Does continuity of a map $f$ imply: $f^{-1}$ maps subbasis onto subbasis?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I am stuck with an exercise, maybe you can help me out here.

> Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space with subbasis $\mathcal{S}$ and let $f: X \longrightarrow X$ be a surjective map.
>
> 1. Show that $f^{-1}(S) \in \mathcal{S}$ for all $S \in \mathcal{S}$ implies that $f$ is continuous.
> 2. Does the converse hold?

${}$

**1.** $\quad$ Any open set can be written as a union of basis elements. A basis element is a finite intersection of elements in the subbasis. By assumption the preimage of a finite intersection of subbasis-elements is a finite intersection of subbasis-elements again and therefore a basis element. Consequently, the preimage of an open set is the union of basis elements - which again is an open set. $\quad \square$

**Question**: Do I even need surjectivity here?

${}$

**2.** $\quad$ I am stuck here. Neither am I able to give a counter-example nor was I able to prove that the converse indeed holds. I somehow have the feeling that the converse does not hold.

**Question**: Do you have any tips on how to tackle this or can you provide an instructional counter-example?

Comment: The converse may not be true. The problem is that although subbasis elements are open, their preimages through continuous maps are only open. However, there is no guarantee that it will be again a subbasis element. To get a counterexample, think of a surjective map which maps non-subbasis open sets to subbasis open sets. That should give you the required counterexample.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. While looking for an example I stumbled across another question related to this one:
${}$
Assume $A,B$ form a subbasis $\mathcal{S}_1$ and $\mathcal{O}$ is open. But $A, \mathcal{O}$ also form another subbasis $\mathcal{S}_2$. Does $\mathcal{O} \notin \mathcal{S}_1$, $f(\mathcal{O}) \in \mathcal{S}_1$ count as a counter-example nevertheless? Or is the argument, that $\mathcal{O} \in \mathcal{S}_2$ is actually an element of some (!) subbasis and therefore not a good counter-example, valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: no surjectivity is needed: the fact that subbasic sets have open preimages is a simple necessary and sufficient condition for continuity in general, because $f^{-1}$ on sets preserves set operations.

The converse need not hold: take $X=\Bbb R$ with the standard subbase

$$\mathcal{S} = \{(-\infty,a),(a,+\infty)\mid a \in \Bbb R\}$$ and $f(x)=x\sin x$ as an example.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still do not see how surjectivity is need. The equivalence of subbasic sets having open preimages and continuity is granted. However, suppose $f$ was not surjective. Then for all $x \in X$ such that $x \notin f(X)$ it holds that $f^{-1}(x) = \emptyset$, doesn't it? The empty set is always open an so we would only have to consider the restriction $f : X \longrightarrow f(X)$ for our considerations regarding continuity. Where's the flaw in my thinking?

Comment: @Octavius I said it was *not* needed. I don’t understand your follow up

Comment: Ups sorry, I misread your sentence. My understanding of your sentence was: "No, (comma!) surjectivity is needed." I now see that there is indeed no comma.